# handleSubmit not reading update as a function

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand why my form isn't reading my updateContact function or my deleteContact function. I've included both in my components>contacts>contacts.js folder and then call them in the ContactForm.js file. Any ideas?

ContactForm.js

```
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


const ContactForm = ({ addContact, setEdit, id, updateContact, f_name, l_name, email, phone, body }) => {
  const [contact, setContact ] = useState({ f_name: '', l_name: '', email: '', phone: 0, body: ''})
  
  useEffect( () => {
    if (id) {
      setContact({ f_name, l_name, email, phone, body })
    }
  }, [])


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (id) {
      updateContact(id, contact)
      setEdit(false)
    } else {
      addContact(contact)
    }
    setContact({ f_name: '', l_name: '', email: '', phone: 0, body: ''})
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label>First Name:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              name='f_name'
              value={contact.f_name}
              onChange={(e) => setContact({...contact, f_name: e.target.value})}
              required
              placeholder='First Name'
            />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Last Name:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name='l_name'
          value={contact.l_name}
          onChange={(e) => setContact({...contact, l_name: e.target.value})}
          required
          placeholder='Last Name'
        />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Email:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name='email'
          value={contact.email}
          onChange={(e) => setContact({...contact, email: e.target.value})}
          required
          placeholder='Email'
        />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Phone Number:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name='number'
          value={contact.phone}
          onChange={(e) => setContact({...contact, phone: e.target.value})}
          required
          placeholder='Phone Number'
        />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Reason for Contacting:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name='body'
          value={contact.body}
          onChange={(e) => setContact({...contact, body: e.target.value})}
          required
          placeholder='Tell Me How I Can Help!'
        ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}

export default ContactForm;
```

It looks like the handleSubmit isn't being connected to the Contacts.js file.

Contacts.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ContactForm from './ContactForm';
import ContactList from './ContactList';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

const Contacts = ({}) => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect( () => {
    axios.get('/api/contacts')
      .then( res => {
        setContacts(res.data)
      })
      .catch( err => console.log(err))
  }, [])
  
  const addContact = (contact) => {
    axios.post('/api/contacts', { contact })
    .then( res => {
      setContacts([...contacts, res.data])
    })
    .catch( err => console.log(err))
  }

  const updateContact = (id, contact) => {
    axios.put(`/api/contacts/${id}`, { contact })
      .then( res => {
        const newUpdatedContacts = contact.map( c => {
          if (c.id === id) {
            return res.data
          }
          return c
        })
        setContacts(newUpdatedContacts)
        navigate('/contacts')
      })
      .catch( err => console.log(err))
  }

  
  const deleteContact = (id) => {
    axios.delete(`/api/contacts/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      setContacts(contacts.filter( c => c.id !== id))
      alert(res.data.message)
      navigate('/contacts')
    })
    .catch( err => console.log(err))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
      <ContactForm addContact={addContact}/>
      <ContactList 
      contacts={contacts}
      deleteContact={deleteContact}
      updateContact={updateContact}
       />
    </>
  )
}

export default Contacts;
```

ContactShow.js

````
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ContactForm from './ContactForm';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Contacts from './Contacts';


const ContactShow = ({deleteContact, updateContact, f_name, l_name, email, phone, body, id}) => {
  const [editing, setEdit] = useState(false)
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({f_name: '', l_name: '', email: '', phone: 0, body: '' })
  const params = useParams();


  useEffect( () => {
    axios.get(`/api/contacts/${params.contactId}`)
    .then( res => setContact(res.data))
    .catch( err => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      { editing ? 
      <>
        <ContactForm
          {...contact}
          updateContact={updateContact}
          setEdit={setEdit}
        />
        <br />
        <Button variant="warning" onClick={() => setEdit(false)}>Cancel</Button>
        <br />
      </>
      :
      <>
     
    <h2>{contact.f_name} {contact.l_name}</h2>
    <h3>Phone: {contact.phone} Email: {contact.email}</h3>
    <p>Comments: {contact.body}</p>
    
    <Button variant="success" onClick={() => setEdit(true)}>Edit</Button>
    <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => deleteContact(id)}>Delete</Button>
    </>
      }
    </>
  )
}


export default ContactShow;```
````

Comment: Where is the implementation of `ContactList`?

Comment: ContactList is in the same folder, 

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';



const ContactList = ({ contacts }) => {
  const [editing, setEdit] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
    <ListGroup> 
      { contacts.map ( c => 
        <>
        <Link to={`/${c.id}`} key={c.id}>
          <ListGroup.Item>{c.f_name} {c.l_name}</ListGroup.Item>.
        </Link>
        </>
        )}
    </ListGroup>
    </>
  )
}

export default ContactList;```

Comment: Where do you render `<ContactShow/>`?